# Which capabilities is required in the simpliest application to accept it on marketplace?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, capability

like in topic: Which capabilities is required in the simpliest application to accept it on marketplace? I have the siply application which for example have 1 button and 1 textBlock and onClick event it display "Hello World!" in TextBox.

I have read specification of each capabilities on msdn and I this easy application doesn't need any of them. But if my application will be accept on marketplace if I submit it with empty Capabilities elements?

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: Ignoring the question of which capabilities settings are required in the config, you really should rethink submitting a Hello world app to the Marketplace. That would do your reputation more harm than good :)

Comment: You'll probably get a more relevant answer on the [Windows Phone StackExchange Site](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the capabilities detector and go with its suggestions for your settings.

From this link http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/windows-phone-7-capabilities:

"The latest update (October 2010) to the Windows Phone 7 tools provided a console application to detect the actual capabilities used by your application if later you want to edit your WMAppManifest.xml to that, this tool is under Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.0\Tools\CapDetect."

Official instruction link for the Capabilities detector here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg180730(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: I think that your answer can be very useful but I'm not sure which file I should give as secound parameter in `CapabilityDetection Rules.xml C:\Path\To\MyApp`. I was try to give the Debug/MyApp.xap there but then nothing happened.

Comment: Added official instruction link for Capabilities detector.. Google is your friend!

Comment: I told that I have read it but I haven't noticed the part about **Using the Marketplace Test Kit to Determine Application Capabilities for Windows Phone OS 7.1 Applications** It was very helpful. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

*Edit - I read the title and most of the question, but didn't read the part about the `Capabilities` section*

Since the question was about the "Capabilities" section of the manifest... one thing to keep in mind is that (at least for now), it doesn't matter what you put in the capabilities section.  When you submit your app for certification, the process automatically scans your app and determines what capabilities are required, and puts them in the app manifest for you.

*end edit*

I'm not sure this is the best place to ask this question.  You might want to try http://create.msdn.com - In my experience, though, they don't fail based on functionality, unless it violates the terms of use (e.g. copyright infringement, sexual themes).  Mostly, they look to see that:

- The application works.
- It doesn't make use of any non-approved APIs
- It doesn't crash
- It handles the back button correctly

They also look at a few other things like:

- Startup time (less than 5 seconds), and
- Memory usage.

There are a bunch of other things that you should be familiar with as well.

The certification requirements, which can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184843%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) are very clear in what they expect, and are pretty well written.

Comment: The question was specifically about the Capabilities settings... not meeting MS requirements, so is appropriate for SO.